# I'm seeing a type error I can't seem to solve when using sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I bet this is a simple fix for someone but I'm racking my brain and can't seem to find the answer... Let's start with my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

"""
import pandas
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import sklearn.metrics
import os

os.chdir("..")

# Set Display options
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# Read in the Mars Crater Data
print("reading data set...")
data = pandas.read_csv('marscrater2_pds.csv', low_memory=(False))
print("cleaning data...")
data_clean = data.dropna()
data_clean['DIAM_CIRCLE_IMAGE'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['DIAM_CIRCLE_IMAGE'], downcast="float")
data_clean['DEPTH_RIMFLOOR_TOPOG'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['DEPTH_RIMFLOOR_TOPOG'], downcast="float")
data_clean['LATITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['LATITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'], downcast="float")
data_clean['LONGITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['LONGITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE'], downcast="float")
data_clean['NUMBER_LAYERS'] = pandas.to_numeric(data_clean['NUMBER_LAYERS'], downcast="integer")


print("analysing data types...")
data_clean.dtypes
data_clean.describe()

print("setting predictors...")
predictors = data_clean[['LATITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE', 'LONGITUDE_CIRCLE_IMAGE',
                         'DIAM_CIRCLE_IMAGE', 'NUMBER_LAYERS']]

print("setting target(s)...")
targets = data_clean["DEPTH_RIMFLOOR_TOPOG"]

print("setting test splits...")
pred_train, pred_test, tar_train, tar_test = train_test_split(predictors, targets, test_size=0.4)


print("shaping test splits...")
pred_train.shape
pred_test.shape
tar_train.shape
tar_test.shape

print("setting classifier...")
classifier=DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier=classifier.fit(pred_train, tar_train)

print("setting up prediction...")
predictions=classifier.predict(pred_test)
print("building model...")
sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(tar_test,predictions)
```

.. I am getting the following error:

> runfile('C:/Users//Documents/Training/IT Nano - Data
> Analyst/Machine Learning/ML (Week 1).py',
> wdir='C:/Users//Documents/Training/IT Nano - Data
> Analyst/Machine Learning') reading data set... cleaning data...
> analysing data types... setting predictors... setting target(s)...
> setting test splits... shaping test splits... setting classifier...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users<username>\Documents\Training\IT Nano - Data
> Analyst\Machine Learning\ML (Week 1).py", line 58, in 
> classifier=classifier.fit(pred_train, tar_train)
>
> File
> "C:\Users<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_classes.py",
> line 890, in fit
> super().fit(
>
> File
> "C:\Users<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_classes.py",
> line 181, in fit
> check_classification_targets(y)
>
> File
> "C:\Users<username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py",
> line 172, in check_classification_targets
> raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
>
> ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point is that your target variable is made of floats (from which label type `continuous` that you can see on your error traceback).

> ‘continuous’: y is an array-like of floats that are not all integers, and is 1d or a column vector.

A `continuous` label type is forbidden for general classification tasks as you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/6b4f82433dc2f219dbff7fe8fa42c10b72379be6/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L172).

*Roughly speaking*, for it to work you need to have a target of `binary` type for binary classification problems, of `multiclass`/`multiclass-multioutput`/`multilabel-indicator` type for multiclass-multilabel classification problems. I would suggest to have a look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html#sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target) to have an overview of the possible types of targets.

Comment: I think I understand... I'll need to categorize the crater depth variable into a binary

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I was able to resolve my issue!